# Filtering Data through relational data in Linq queries not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, extension-methods

```
public IEnumerable<AccountCategory> GetAllAccountsCategories(Guid applicationSubscriberId)
{
    return _context.AccountCategories.Include(s => s.AccountSubCategories)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.AccountTypes)
        .ThenInclude(d =>d.ChartOfAccounts.Where(c => c.ApplicationSubscriberId == applicationSubscriberId));           
}
```

This is a query that I need to generate for my project, but it raises an exception:

> The property expression 'd => {from ChartOfAccount c in d.ChartOfAccounts where ([c].ApplicationSubscriberId == __applicationSubscriberId_0) select [c]}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393

I have tried every possible option but its still not working. someone suggest a stored procedure will work, but I don't do stored procedures.

Comment: Please be more (much more!) specific. *What* isn't working? *Where* do you need help? In its present form your post is not a question.

Comment: Duplicate of [Entity framework core: The property expression 'xx' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44034149/861716).

Comment: I suggested a duplicate. After that you added two more lines asking for more help. Did you even open the duplicate? It tells *exactly* what's wrong here.

Comment: Of course I do, and I am still doing, thanks

Comment: The issues are quite different, in this case, I wanna return accountcategories, which is the topmost class

Comment: You have `ThenInclude` with `Where`. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to filter will determine the answer:

My guess is that you want all Account categories which have an AccountType.ChartOfAccounts.Subscriber matching the ID I provide. This will return the account category, and eager load all account types and their respective chart of accounts.

```
var accountCategories = _context.AccountCategories
  .Include(ac => ac.AccountSubCategories)
  .ThenInclude(sc => sc.AccountTypes)
  .ThenInclude(at => at.ChartOfAccounts)
  .Where(ac => ac.AccountSubCategories
     .Any(sc => sc.AccountTypes
        .Any(at => at.ChartOfAccounts
           .Any(ac => ac.ApplicationSubscriberId == applicationSubscriberId));
```

Querying on deeply nested criteria is a bit of a pain.

If you instead want to filter the ChartOfAccounts of each account category returned to only include charts with that subscriber id, EF cannot filter entity sets so you would have to select on that filtered collection separately. Depending on how high that filtering needed to happen (I.e. include/exclude account types and/or sub-categories) would govern the complexity of the query. Essentially to filter child collections you need to Select them explicitly alongside the top level entities.

If the above example doesn't reflect what you are after, then please append an example data state and the desired output and we can see if/how that might be possible.